# second layer of exec not returning thread

Tags: php, background, exec

I'm breaking up one script into two scripts, so that I can get the second script running all inputs in parallel instead of series, which takes a long time.  Below is what it looks like broken up into two. For some reason, I'm not seeing logging after the second exec(snmpwalk).

I was following [exec in background](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php) to get the first exec to not return the thread so it can have the second script run in the background. Specifically, I am using what vi_pa at hotmail dot com  recommended at that link.

status_parallel.php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ); 
$cng_ip_array = array("1.18.8.78",  "4.13.8.75", "4.13.81.72", "4.18.8.76", "4.18.8.22", "4.18.8.81", "4.18.8.74", "4.18.8.23", "4.18.8.156", "4.18.8.73", "40.18.8.77", "4.18.8.80", "2.19.19.80", ); //these are not real ip's

foreach($cng_ip_array as $ip)
{
    $logFile = "/opt/scripts/catv_monitoring/catv/phperror." . $ip . ".log";
    print "ip: " . $ip . "\n";
    exec("php getStatus.php $ip 2>$logFile >&- <&- >$logFile &"); //http://php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php
}
?>
```

getStatus.php:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
error_reporting(E_ALL ); //& ~E_NOTICE | ~E_WARNING
echo "hi " . $argv[1] . " " . date('h:i:s'); //this is what I see in log
$ip = $argv[1];

$output=array();
print "Doing snmpwalk for ip, " . $ip . ", next. Please wait. " . date('h:i:s') . "\n";
exec(" snmpwalk -v2c -c commString $ip OIDnums ", $output); //this works in old script, so should be fine here
//but snmpwalk does not return and I don't see next logging

foreach($output as $line) { //each outputline of snmpwalk
    //do things
} //foreach output line of snmpwalk

echo "done with status for " . $ip . " " . date('h:i:s') . "\n"; //I don't see this
?>
```

I'm seeing this in each log file created for screen output in the status_parallel script:

typical output in logs (time stamp was updated for logs) -

```
prompt:$ more phperror.<ip>.log
hi <ip> 07:16:25Doing snmpwalk for ip, <ip>, next. Please wait.
```

I checked background processes, and after the script is run, no processes are still running in the background:

```
prompt:$ ps -elf | grep getStatus
0 S employeeID 29635  3604  0  80   0 -  1597 pipe_w 07:21 pts/0    00:00:00 grep getStatus
```

I think the second exec is getting affected by the first exec output and & I gave it.  I need to have the first exec allow the process it runs to be in the background.  The second exec needs to return and continue the code.  Any idea how to get the second process to return?

***Update***
I tried replacing 
`exec("snmpwalk...",$output)` 
with

```
`exec("ls",$output)`
echo "output results: \n";
var_dump($output);
```

and the logging file shows the directory listing but the thread never comes back, and the log file doesn't show "done with status for". This is important because I need to write the snmpwalk results to my DB.
Example:

```
$ more phperror.<ip>.log
hi <ip> 08:26:19Doing snmpwalk for ip, <ip>, next. Please wait. 08:26:19
output results:
array(61) {
  [0]=>
  string(18) "ModemData.csv"
  [1]=>
  string(18) "ModemData.sql"
  [2]=>
  string(9) "Keith.txt"
  [3]=>
  string(16) "KeithCompare.php"
...
```

***Update2***

I commented out the "//do things", and I'm seeing the end of my logging in the file:

```
...
shane.file
triad_addresses.good.php
triad_addresses.php
done with status for <ip> 08:44:55
```

I'll look into possible issues with "do things"....

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with code that I didn't detail here.  When I fixed it, the problem went away